# How to change start of vs code terminal directory path to current workspace folder

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Hey i need help with VS code terminal ...

so  suppose i opened a "project" folder in vscode

and powershell terminal inside vscode
showing directory path like this:
PS D:\work\project>

Which is good I don't have to navigate cd ... To folder, That's what I want, but only problem is it show path starting from "D- Drive\work"

And now inside "project" in vs code as task required,
If i create some more nested Folders and file
suppose(hello\hello.py)
and now vs code powershell terminal showing path like this:
PS D:\work\project\hello>

but i want terminal directory path to start from "project" ,
something like
PS project\hello>

how to achieve this ?

So basically in vs code if i open a folder
terminal should start its directory path from that folder

Is their any solution to that..

I tried terminal.integrated.cwd = "${workspaceFolder}
In both user/workspace setting.json
But it's not working it's still the same

Comment: is this a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)?